# Ionic/Angular how can i change style with string value?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4, ionic5

tv series project. And its shows avarage points inside of badge ( IMBD Points ). My datas coming from a json. I want to make like if that point bigger than 8.0, make badge background color green,if its 6.0 - 8.0 make it yellow, if its 5- then red like that. How can i do that ? Thanks for help!

I tried make like

```
<ion-badge *ngIf="item.vote_average>8" style="background-color: rgb(110, 109, 37);">
```

Its works but i cant check all situations. Can i make if-if-if like c# ? i tried it but it didnt worked too. Its just allow me to use 1 *ngIf

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this.

For example you can try any of this:

- [`ngSwitch`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch)
- [`ngStyle`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle)
- write function that returns correct color code:

  [style.background-color]="item.vote_average > 8 ? 'rgb(110, 109, 37)' : 'rgb(10, 23, 0)'"

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to use CSS classes. Set the colors as you need them. I just put in the same in each class.

**Your CSS file**

```
.larger-than-eight{
    background-color: rgb(110, 109, 37);
}

 .six-to-eight{
    background-color: rgb(110, 109, 37);
}

 .less-than-six{
    background-color: rgb(110, 109, 37);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-badge [class]="getClass(item.vote_average)">
```

**TS file**

```
getClass(value: number): string {
    if (value > 8) {
        return 'larger-than-eight';
    }

    if (value > 6 && value < 8) {
        return 'six-to-eight';
    }

    if (value < 6) {
        return 'less-than-six';
    }
}
```